# How can I get the longest winning and losing streak of a player using Laravel Eloquent or Php?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I've currently got a table which stores some football (or soccer) results.

Each row in the table is for a particular player in that match with the outcome of the match.

outcome_id 1 is win, outcome_id 2 is lose, outcome_id 3 is draw.

I want to try and find out the longest winning streak for a player. For example, assume I am user_id 1 which has 10 rows in this table because I've played 10 matches. Order by match_date_time (so that the data is in the order of the matches played), how can I calculate the number of matches I've won in a row? So i can find the longest winning streak per player. I also want to do the same for longest losing streak too.

```
Schema::create('player_match_stats', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();
        $table->unsignedInteger('season_id')->nullable();
        $table->foreignId('match_id')->constrained('matches')->onDelete('cascade');
        $table->unsignedInteger('user_id');
        $table->unsignedInteger('outcome_id')->nullable();
        $table->unsignedInteger('team_name_id')->nullable();
        $table->dateTime('match_date_time')();
        $table->timestamps();
    });
```

Ideally I'd want to be able to do this via Eloquent/PHP if possible.

Any help would be highly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Only idea I have is to get all matches ordered by match_date_time, loop through an use some counters.

Comment: Hey, thanks for your comment. How would you handle losses and draws in-between the count?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution:

1. You get dates of the loses and drew of the player into array.
2. You make a for loop. You make query to count wins between i and i + 1 dates. You have to take note that at first run (i == 0) you need to get wins before that date, and at last run (i == length of array) you need to get wins after that date.
3. You make a variable to always store the highest number.

Hope this helps :)

Comment: That wouldn't work if there is a break in between. E.g I won the first 4 matches. Lost once, won another 2 matches then drew the rest.

Comment: Okay so you need the last draw or the last lose's time and it will work, I didn't consider there's drew also, but it doesn't make a big difference :)

Comment: Oh I see now, I was thinking in current (living) win streak, and you meant all time win streak

Comment: Ah yes I meant all time winning streak. Sorry I should've clarified.

Comment: Ok, I've modified my answer to suit your needs. A lil' more complicated, but if you need help with the code just let me know. cheers

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to help. Do you mind helping with the code? I've been stuck at this for two days trying to use for loops, foreach loops and while loops. I've come up short every time.